# Evaluate the limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I am hung up on this limit: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}}{x}$

I must be missing something related to dealing with square roots but I can not for the life of me figure out what.

Here is my work so far:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{(\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x})(\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x})}{x(\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x})}$

$=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x}^2 + (\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}) - (\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x})-\sqrt{1-x}^2}{x(\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x})}$

$= \displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1+x - 1-x}{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}}= 0$.

After this I end up with the answer 0, but I know that it should come out to 1. If someone could look over this and see where I am going wrong and point me in the right direction I will be eternally thankful!

Comment: The limit of the numerator is $2$, the limit of the denominator is $0$. So...

Comment: Check the numerator of your last step. It should be $(1+x)-(1-x) = 2x$. Check the denominator of your last step. It seems like you're missing an $x$ from the previous step.

Comment: There's no need to be fancy. Look at the original limit and think about julien's comment. You should also consider the left and right hand limits separately.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to work it out and see if I understand the suggestions now.

Comment: Your edit (please when editing the original post, indicate that you have done so, so that answers addressing your initial work do not become irrelevant): you should end with numerator $1 + x - (1 - x) = 1 + x - 1 + x = 2x$ And your denominator: the sqrt. expressions should be subtracted, not added.

Comment: Both you and @amWhy are working way too hard. See the first comment above!

Comment: It is coming back to me now, I waited way too long between algebra and calc classes. I understand what to do now and why. Thank you all very much.

Sorry about the edits, I thought when I filled out the reason for edits it would be annotated somewhere on the post. I will make sure to indicate what they are better from now on.

Comment: @Harald I think it's worth addressing errors in algebra when they are apparent. math.se isn't just about getting the right answer, it's also about helping others learn, e.g. by being clear about algebraic errors.

Comment: @amWhy Point taken. And thanks for editing your answer; I feel I can upvote it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}}{x}$$

Note that evaluating $\quad \displaystyle \lim \frac{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}}{x}\;$ as $\;x\to 0\;$ gives you $\;2\;$ in the numerator, and $\;0\;$ in the denominator. So the task that ultimately remains is to evaluate the limits as $\;x \to 0^+\,$ and as $\;x \to 0^-$.

---

Hint: (prior to post's edit): Regarding your algebraic manipulations, if you are attempting to "simplify" the expression to make the limit more evident: try multiplying numerator and denominator by $\;\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x}$, and be careful with algebra!

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{(\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x})(\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x})}{(\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x})x}$$  $$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x}{(\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x})x}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x}}$$

Now be sure to take the limit as $x \to 0^+$ and as $x\to 0^-$

Comment: Woops, I ment to type a subtraction in my second step. I believe my third step reflects the outcome with the sign corrected. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: This is going to be a very stupid question I am certain, but how do you get from (sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})(sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}) = 2x ?

Comment: See my comment below your answer, after your edit.

Comment: Ha, thank you! you are a saint.

Comment: You're welcome, user59012!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question you *meant* to ask was to find $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x}}{x}.$$ This can be seen to be $1$ by binomial expansion of the terms in the numerator, and some cancellation. The limit of the expression you gave doesn't exist.